# É possível que um script saiba por onde ele foi chamado?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sh

Tenho um `script.sh` e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma dele saber por onde foi chamado.

ex:

```
comando=$(existe algum comando pra isso?)
variavel=$AlgumaVariavelDeAmbienteTalvez

if [[ $comando == "x" ]]; then
  echo "fui chamado pelo prompt do windows"

elseif [[ $variavel == "y" ]]; then
  echo "fui chamado pelo terminal do git bash"

elseif [[ $variavel == "z" ]]; then
  echo "fui chamado pelo ctrl + r (executar do windows)"

elseif [[ $comando == "teste" ]]; then
  echo "fui clicado!!<---"
fi
```

Como no exemplo, existe alguma variável ou comando que me permita identificar como ele foi chamado??

Comment: Talvez o máximo que dê pra saber é se o script foi executado em um terminal ou não: https://askubuntu.com/q/729904 - Mas saber se foi via menu executar ou double-click acho que não faz diferença (ambos caem no caso "sem terminal")

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar as variaveis de ambiente [`$0`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280454/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-in-the-bash-shell) e [`$SHELL`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277944/what-sets-the-shell-environment-variable), veja só:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "Linha de Comando: %s\n" $0
printf "Shell           : %s\n" $SHELL
```

Possível Saída:

```
Linha de Comando: ./script.sh
Shell           : /bin/bash
```